# How can I call a group of statements within a function synchronously in javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

After reading callback functions in JavaScript, I am facing some issues implementing them. Here is my code snippet which I am calling in my background page:

```
var f=0;
function sendDataToServer(message,sender,callback) {

    chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{},function(dataUri){
        message['screenshot']=dataUri;
        f=1;
        console.log("here !"+message['screenshot']); // here screenshot works fine 
    });
    message['allLogs']=dataStore[sender.tab.id];
    callback(message);
}
```

I am taking a screenshot of the page, adding it to the object. I am then adding another property to the object, and then I am calling the callback function.

This is my callback function:

```
sendDataToServer(message,sender,function (message) {
    console.log(f);
    for(var i in message){
        if(message.hasOwnProperty(i))
            console.log(i+' '+message[i]);
        }
    });
}
```

So as per the syntax and rules of JavaScript, the value of **f** in the callback should be 1 but it is zero and there is no property as screenshot in the message object.

I want to take screenshot before calling the callback function, so that I can have screenshot in the callback.

What am I doing wrong and how can this be rectified ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the callback to inside the `captureVisibleTab` function. As such:

```
chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(null,{},function(dataUri){
    message['screenshot']=dataUri;
    f=1;
    console.log("here !"+message['screenshot']); // here screenshot works fine 

    message['allLogs']=dataStore[sender.tab.id];
    callback(message);
});
```

To explain what is happening here:

The `function(dataUri)` declaration is the callback function of `captureVisibleTab`. By moving our `callback(message)` inside here, we are telling JavaScript to execute `callback(message)` only when `captureVisibleTab` is complete.

Before, as per your example, having `callback(message)` outside and after the `function(dataUri)` callback, meant that we were performing `callback(message)` *before* completion of `function(dataUri)`, and therefore, your screenshot was not fully processed yet.

Answer (score 0):

Read about closures in javascript. Enclose your statements (which you want to execute synchronously) into closures and then place that closure in a callback. They will execute synchronously. This jsfiddle might help you [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/umaar/fsxxm)

```
Jsfiddle
```

Comment: It's better to include your answer here, (over in a fiddle can be a nice bonus).  The only thing I can really get from your answer is "use closures".